# How to Determine Week of Year From Date?

Tags: java, date

How can I determine what the week of the year is from a given date in Java; where the start date is January 1. I see a number of examples such as using `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` however this is defined by locale resulting in a varying start date.

To be clear; by week of year I mean: which of the 52 weeks in a year starting from January 1.

There are numerous questions related to the locale specific behavior of `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` here on Stack; I didn't see the answer I need in any of them however.

The problem that can occur is that for `Locale.US`, the first week of the year can be the last week of the prior year; so Dec 31 2013 will show as week 1 of 2014. I have seen `Locale.GERMAN` as acting as I would expect but I would prefer not to use this.

A typical recommendation I want to avoid:

```
Calendar aCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
aCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: can you add some code that explains what you wrote in explanation

Comment: What *exact* meaning of "week of year" are you after? There are several possible options.

Comment: The week of the year is *relative* to locale, isn't it?

Comment: You can always set the desired locale if you want to use a single locale

Comment: According to the ISO standard, the first week of a year is defined to be the week that contains the 4th of january. That means you should call cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4) first, because I'm not sure if just setting the locale will do the same.

Comment: *"A typical recommendation I want to avoid:"*  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a formula on Wikipedias page of [ISO Week Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week) which is

```
week(date) = (ordinal(date) - weekday(date) + 10) / 7
```

with the following logic

> Method: Using ISO weekday numbers (running from 1 for Monday to 7 for
>   Sunday), subtract the weekday from the ordinal date, then add 10.
>   Divide the result by 7. Ignore the remainder; the quotient equals the
>   week number. If the week number thus obtained equals 0, it means that
>   the given date belongs to the preceding (week-based) year. If a week
>   number of 53 is obtained, one must check that the date is not actually
>   in week 1 of the following year.

Apart from that, use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and/or wait for the new [java.time](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

Comment: Gedalya said this was affected by locale.

Comment: @claj Can you include a link to the mentioned Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 0):

### Unclear Question

As mentioned in the comments…

- You have not clearly defined what you mean by weeks. Definitions vary. Some industries or companies have their own peculiar definitions. Some are even chosen arbitrarily, meaning you cannot calculate them.
- [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *Data elements and interchange formats – Information interchange – Representation of dates and times* is a formal standard that defines precisely what is meant by a week. See [this brief description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) and [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering). Adoption seems to be growing across industries and the globe.

Mac users can see the week numbers in the Calendar app by checking the `Preferences > Advanced > Show week numbers` checkbox.

### Joda-Time

The third-party open-source date-time library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), uses ISO 8601 as its defaults. This includes the standard week.

A [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object knows its time zone, and knows its standard week-of-year.

### Example Code

```java
// Better to specify a time zone explicitly than rely on default.
// This list is not quite up-to-date (read page for details): http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris");

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( timeZone );
//DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2014, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0 );

DateTime.Property weekProp = dateTime.weekOfWeekyear();
int weekNumber = weekProp.get();
String weekString = weekProp.getAsText();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "weekProp: " + weekProp );
System.out.println( "weekNumber: " + weekNumber );
System.out.println( "weekString: " + weekString );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-14T05:57:55.635+01:00
weekProp: Property[weekOfWeekyear]
weekNumber: 3
weekString: 3
```